# Java: How do randomly initialize the order of a user-definied size 2D array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a program where the user picks the size of a square NxN array, where N is the number they pick and represents the number of rows and columns.

My context of my program is to make an N puzzle game. So whatever size the user picks, the values will be 0 through the  number of array spaces - 1. For example, if user picks 3 for the size, this will be a 3 x 3 array, which means there will be 9 spaces for numbers, and the numbers will be 0 - 8.

This is my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);      
    System.out.print("Enter dimension n of an nxn puzzle:");      

    int n = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

    int[][] puzzle = new int[n][n]; 
}
```

So basically I have to figure out how to initialize it so the values are in a random order, and the values have to be with those particular numbers (0-8 or whatever the case is based on what the user wants).

Also, we are not allowed to use any external algorithms such as the Fisher-Yates Shuffle algorithm.

Comment: I mean your array is creating fine, now make a loop to randomly populate it?

Comment: So basically when you say `we are not allowed to use any external algorithms such as the Fisher-Yates Shuffle algorithm`, you must code your own Random generator, right?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the dimension of the array does not matter at all.

A simple way of random initialization would be:

1. Initialize the array in the order the values appear
2. Iterate through all elements and interchange their values with the value of a randomly chosen element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

This might be your way, unless every number is only allowed to appear once:

```
public int[][] initRandomArray(int n){
    int[][] puzzle = new int[n][n];
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int x = 0; x < puzzle.length; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < puzzle.length; y++)
            puzzle[x][y] = random.nextInt(n * n);
    return puzzle;
}
```

**EDIT:** 
I think I got your question now. This should help you:

```
public int[][] initRandomArray(int n){
    int[][] puzzle = new int[n][n];

    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < n * n; i++)
        numbers.add(i);

    Random random = new Random();
    for(int x = 0; x < puzzle.length; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < puzzle.length; y++)
            puzzle[x][y] = numbers.remove(random.nextInt(numbers.size()));
    return puzzle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested for loop to iterate through the array, assigning each value of the array as you iterate via the random class Java provides. If you can't have repeating numbers in the array you may need a check if the number has already been used

```
Random rnd = new Random();

//inside nested for loop
while (value has already been picked){
    // gives a random value btwen 0 and (n*n)-1
    value = rnd.nextInt((n*n));
}

// value has not been used
puzzle [i][j]= value;
```

there are many ways to check if a value has been used (I used a boolean array when I had a project like this)

Comment: This solution only works if the values are consecutive numbers. I am not really sure if we can assume this, see the 2nd-last paragraph of the original question. Furthermore, if n gets large, you will probably have to generate lots of random numbers until you get an unused one.